# How does the Twitter app 'remember' user data even after clearing?

Tags: applications, twitter

I'm trying to automate Twitter usage across multiple accounts, but handle login via restoring session cookies / user data. 
Somehow, clearing cache/user data does nothing to log the current user out, and I've been trying to figure out all day where the persisting user data is stored.

As you would expect, `pm clear com.twitter.android` results in everything (except .../lib) in `/data/data/com.twitter.android`, and corresponding `/data/user/0/com.twitter.android/`  being wiped. I would have thought this would effectively reset the app back the its initial install state, but reopening the app just restores those directories to as they were before clearing and the account remains logged in... however I can't find any backed up data that its restoring from anywhere!

The following files are the only ones I could find with auth tokens that persist after clearing cache & data. But even clearing these does nothing.

```
/data/system/notification_log.db
/data/system_ce/0/accounts_ce.db
```

Anyone got any ideas? Working on Android Oreo 8.0 (26).

Many thanks.

Comment: Checked `Android` in your internal storage? Or other folders with names related to Twitter? Could be something there.

Comment: There is a directory `http_responses` under `Android/data/com.twitter.android` in internal storage. However this also gets wiped by `pm clear com.twitter.android`. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: IMO it definitely has to be in the internal storage to be persistent, though the filename might not immediately ring your bells...